# How to show the validation in the second input only?

Tags: reactjs

The user has the possibility to click a button and generate the input box. I have put a condition that if the user types the same word to show the error validation below the input.

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bell-cex2of?file=/src/AddLanguage.js

What I want to do is to show the error validation only in the second input.
How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you only have one error for multiple inputs?

Comment: It's just two inputs max and I'm trying to show it only in the second input.

Comment: Based on your code right now, react has no clue who that error belongs to. All react knows is that it's rendering each item in the array and if there is a error render that error with the item. What you need to think about is how you're relating the error to the array item.